# Yii2 kartik Export Menu not dowloading files from Live server,Shows Internal server error

Tags: php, yii2, export-to-csv

I am using kartik's **ExportMenu** to generate csv and PDF files. 
Its working properly in my local server.
But When I moved to my godaddy server,Export Menu is not generating any document file.
When I tried it shows me Internal Server error.

Attaching the screenshot.

[image]

How can I download it...

Comment: try checking the error_logs of your domain to troubleshoot

Comment: Shows no error in log

Comment: it will show in error_logs and it's probably a permission issue,

Comment: I have given full permission to the project.
i hosted in go daddy..when I checked the error log it shows empty

Comment: which errorlog you have checked inside tour web directory? or the domain errorlogs via cpanel

Comment: Via Cpanel..
One more thing,My projects runs in a beta folder in my server!!